# How to solve this question by using convolution?

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution

I had previously posted this question but my method was wrong in it. 
Two signals are given:

$$x[n]=2^nu[n]$$
$$h[n]=u[n]$$

I have to find $y[n]$. I have spent hours on this question but I am unable to solve it. Kindly please tell me the way to solve it.

Comment: I cannot see any $y[n]$ in your equations. Looks like a homework, maybe this tag is needed here

Comment: I assume from your title you need to solve for the convolution of x[n] and h[n]. It would help direct the best answer if you please write out the base equation for convolution in terms of x[n] and h[n] and then show the steps up to the point where you are confused or stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that $y[n] = h[n] * x[n]$, then 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 y[n]  &\stackrel{(a)}{=} h[n] * x[n]\\
 &\stackrel{(b)}{=} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}
 h[m]x[n-m]\\
 &\stackrel{(c)}{=} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}
 u[m]2^{n-m}u[n-m]\\
 &\stackrel{(d)}{=}2^n
 \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}
 u[m]2^{-m}u[n-m]\\
 &\stackrel{(e)}{=}2^n
 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}
 2^{-m}u[n-m]\\
 &\stackrel{(f)}{=}2^n
 \sum_{m=0}^{n}
 2^{-m}\\
 &\stackrel{(g)}{=}2^n
 \frac{1 - (\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}}\\
 &\stackrel{(h)}{=}2^{n+1} - 1
\end{split}
\end{equation}

(a) is the convolution symbol.

(b) is using the definition of discrete convolution.

(c) replacing the quantities.

(d) $2^n$ is independent of the summation index.

(e) $u[m]=1$ if $m\geq 0$ and $0$ otherwise.

(f) if $n-m<0$, or if $n<m$ then the summation is zero. So we have (for non-zero quantities), $m = 0 \ldots n$.

(g) Using geometric series

(h) rearrangements.

Comment: You're videos are REALLY NICE. I mostly use R and Rcpp but was tinking about delving into python and C++. Do you happen to have pdfs of your videos ?

Comment: Hello @markleeds .. thank you for your interest. I'm glad you found them useful. Unfortunately, I do not have any specific "pdfs" other than the official C++ and Python-related modules websites, that I mention in the description of the videos.